# How to change IOS wallpaper using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Just getting started using Xamarin, and I can't really find anything in the documentation regarding setting the wallpaper for an IOS device.

Is this possible? The only snippets I have found seem targeted at Android only?

Comment: If there is no way to do so in Objective C, you won't get it from Xamarin.iOS either.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change wallpaper on iOS from code